# Date Manipulation with a time string

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to modify some scripts that take spreadsheet entries to create calendar events and I'm having difficulties with the time formatting.
Basically my problem is that my times are going to be coming in as a string and I need to correctly attach that to a new date format.

```
timetext = "9:30 AM"
```

Code:

```
function createBlock(timetext, duration){

var eventTitle = "Code Block - Interrupt OK";  
var date = new Date();
var eventStart = new Date(timetext);
Logger.log(date);
Logger.log(eventStart);
```

Logger says:

"[19-02-06 12:57:48:097 PST] Wed Feb 06 15:57:48 GMT-05:00 2019

[19-02-06 12:57:48:098 PST] Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 GMT-05:00 1969"

```
eventStart.setYear(date.getYear());    
Logger.log(eventStart);
```

Leads to:

[19-02-06 12:57:48:098 PST] Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2019

Which is not at all the expected behavior.

> I want to create a valid Date() for today, with the string time input of something like "9:30 AM".

Comment: Spreadsheet dates/times are automatically converted to date objects. Just `getValues()`. Make sure your date/time is valid in Google sheets-they'll be aligned right, if they're valid.

Comment: I can't do that because the "9:30" is a timestamp created once on a different day, NOT the day I want for the items. I need to feed in strings. Although maybe I can do what you say and then change the date part leaving the time alone... hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Date constructor to create whatever date you want:

```
function todaysDateWithMyTime(hours, minutes) {
  var hours=hours || 9;//added for testing
  var minutes=minutes || 30;//added for testing
  var d=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate(),hours, minutes);
  var s=Utilities.formatDate(d, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a");
  Logger.log(s);//debugging
  return s;
}
```

- [Date Constructor Syntax Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)